# Can I make Git's core.autocrlf ignore a file?

Tags: git, bash, core.autocrlf

Is there a way to make Git's core.autocrlf ignore a specific file?

I'm working on a Linux project with some people who are on Windows and we have this bash script in the repository that is executed on a virtual machine (Vagrant + VirtualBox) during its provisioning phase. The problem is that when the Windows users pull from the repo, git's autocrlf adds the CR character to every line and Vagrant complains about it when executing the script. Is there a way to make Git not add the CR character for that file?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the '.gitattributes' file (and that's even the recommended way of doing, and do not rely on autocrlf setting).